# Program stops working with inputs above 8000

Tags: python

I wrote the following credit card program in response to a question on this site ([Credit card balance exercise in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363358/credit-card-balance-exercise-in-python/29373356#29373356)):

```
def main(rb):
    count = 0
    while rb > 0:
        rb = rb*(0.18/12 + 1) - 120
        count += 1
    return count, round(rb, 2)

print(main(input('Balance: ')))   #Balance: 1200
```

It calculates the number of repayments that will be made and the final balance. The OP was interested in an original balance of 1200 but I changed it so the user can input their own original balance. For a value of 8000 and below the answer comes in a fraction of a second. Above 8000 no answer comes ever. The terminal just stays blank. I've never come across this behaviour before. I am baffled by this. Can anyone replicate it? Why does it happen?

Comment: What does "stops working" mean - does it throw an exception of have unexpected behavior or go into an infinite loop or open a wormhole?

Comment: For 8000 and below the answer comes in a fraction of a second. Above 8000 no answer comes ever. The terminal just stays blank. I've never come across this behaviour before.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . Adding a print statement inside the loop would soon fix your bafflement.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that before. This was just too unexpected, although it shouldn't be - just consider Greece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see why it hangs by stepping through the loop once with `rb = 8001`.

```
8001 * (0.18 / 12 + 1) - 120 ~= 8001.014999999999
```

With values <= 8000, the value decreases, with values > 8000, the value increases so `rb >= 0` will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

$8000 * (1 + 0.18/12) - $120 = $8000.

Therefore when you simulate the payments you get an infinite loop.

That your code actually terminates for an input of $8000 is just luck because of the way the floats have rounded. If the calculations were done exactly, the program wouldn't terminate.

Comment: I've actually changed the first line in the while loop so the result for rb is rounded to two decimal places. For money, there are never more than two decimal places. The intermediate values are meant to be real in particular months. With the change it stops working above 7999.